# How to import EXPORT_TAGS to EXPORTS_OK?

Tags: perl, module

Trying to group my module exports using tags, I want to avoid listing the names more than once, so I tried this:

```
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'command_types' => [qw(ENQ ACK NAK)],
    'commands' => [qw(A B C)],
    'status_codes' => [qw(OK FAILED)],
    'default' => [
        qw(:status_codes :command_types :status_codes)
    ]);
our @EXPORT = @{$EXPORT_TAGS{':default'}};
our @EXPORT_OK = @{$EXPORT_TAGS{':default'}};
```

But unfortunately Perl 5.18 tells me something about an undefined array reference for `@{$EXPORT_TAGS{':default'}}` ("*Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference* ..."). However when I remove the outer `@{...}`, Perl no longer complains, but the result (array reference instead of an array) is wrong.

What did I miss?

**Update:**

When I remove the colons from `:default`, the error message disappears, but then I get an error about `Can't export symbol: :command_types`. If I remove the colon from `:command_types` I don't get an error any more (at this point), but wouldn't that try to export a *symbol* named `command_types` instead of all symbols for tag `command_types`?

The result effectively is `@EXPORT = qw(status_codes command_types status_codes)` then.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland: You are right, it's from editing while trying different variants. But I hope you agree that the *hash key* (e.g. `:default`) has nothing to do with the type of error I'm seeing. Fixed anyway.

Comment: Re: *"has nothing to do with the type of error I'm seeing"* I tested this now and I get exactly that error (`Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference ...`) if I include the colon. If I remove the colon it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland: So that would mean the Perl *compiler* actually tries to do hash lookup (the error message reads like a compiler error to me)? I thought the assignment happens at (early) runtime. But actually yes: You seem to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html), you should not include the leading colons for the tag names in the `%EXPORT_TAGS` hash.

So you could also try something like this:

```
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'command_types' => [qw(ENQ ACK NAK)],
    'commands' => [qw(A B C)],
    'status_codes' => [qw(OK FAILED)],
);
my @default_tags = qw(status_codes command_types commands);
my @default;
push @default, @{$EXPORT_TAGS{$_}} for @default_tags;
our @EXPORT = @default;
our @EXPORT_OK = @default;
```

Comment: You can avoid the extra variables using map like this: `@EXPORT = map { @{$EXPORT_TAGS{$_}} } qw(status_codes command_types status_codes); @EXPORT_OK = @EXPORT`.

Comment: @U.Windl ...your `map` idea, but a bit more dynamic: `push @EXPORT, map { @{$EXPORT_TAGS{$_ }} } (keys %EXPORT_TAGS);` (ie, if the tags ever get updated, no need to remember to update the `qw()` in the `map` command.